# How to terminate thread using condition returned by wx.CallAfter()?

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, wxpython, progress-bar

I am very new to wxPython and also not familiar with thread concept. I would appreciate a lot if anyone could provide info sources or suggestion to my question.

I had created a GUI using wxpython to allow users run my script with inputs. Since one step takes 20 min to run so I plan to create a Progress Dialog to show users progress and allow them to abort it. I had tested this using the sample code below.

However, I couldn't stop WorkThread even though I clicked the Stop Button in Progress Dialog. I tried 
 1. make if statement using return value from pb.sendMessage() 
 2. create the ProgressDialog object when WorkThread starts and call ProgressDialog.abort 
but none of them work. I wonder if there's conceptual mistakes implementing code like this to achieve what I want to do? Or if this can work with correction? Any hint would be appreciated!!

```
class WorkThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        """Init Worker Thread Class."""
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()  # start the thread

    def run(self):

        for i in range(10):
            time.sleep(1)
            val = 100 / 10
            wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, "update", step=val)
        print 'Finish Run'

class ProgressDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self):

        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, None)
        self.abort = False
        self.progress = 0

        bSizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.gauge = wx.Gauge(self, wx.ID_ANY, 100, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.GA_HORIZONTAL)
        self.gauge.SetValue(0)

        self.m_button1 = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Stop Training", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        bSizer2.Add(self.gauge, 0, 0, 5)
        bSizer2.Add(self.m_button1, 0, 0, 5)

        self.SetSizer(bSizer2)
        self.Layout()
        self.Centre(wx.BOTH)

        ## Connect Events

        self.m_button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_cancel)
        pub.subscribe(self.updateProgress, "update")

    def updateProgress(self, step):
        self.progress += step

        if self.abort:
            self.Update()
            self.Close()
        elif self.progress >= 100:
            self.gauge.SetValue(self.progress)
            self.Update()
            self.Close()
        else:
            self.gauge.SetValue(self.progress)

    def on_cancel(self, event):
        """Cancels the conversion process"""
        self.abort = True
        print 'Click'
        # pub.unsubscribe(self.if_abort, 'cancel')

    def __del__(self):
        pass


########################################################################################

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.btn = btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Start Thread")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onButton(self, event):
        btn = event.GetEventObject()
        btn.Disable()
        WorkThread()
        self.dlg = ProgressDialog()
        self.dlg.ShowModal()
        btn.Enable()

app = wx.App()
frame = MainFrame(None)
frame.Show(True)
# start the applications
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a method within the thread to stop it.
You should also wait for it to stop.
Here is an option using your code:

```
from threading import Thread
import wx
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub
import time
class WorkThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        """Init Worker Thread Class."""
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stop_work_thread = 0
        self.start()  # start the thread

    def run(self):
        for i in range(10):
            if self.stop_work_thread == 1:
                break
            time.sleep(1)
            val = 100 / 10
            wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, "update", step=val)
        wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, "finish")
        return

    def stop(self):
        self.stop_work_thread = 1

class ProgressDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.abort = False
        self.progress = 0

        bSizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.gauge = wx.Gauge(self, wx.ID_ANY, 100, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.GA_HORIZONTAL)
        self.gauge.SetValue(0)

        self.m_button1 = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Stop Training", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        bSizer2.Add(self.gauge, 0, 0, 5)
        bSizer2.Add(self.m_button1, 0, 0, 5)

        self.SetSizer(bSizer2)
        self.Layout()
        self.Centre(wx.BOTH)

        ## Connect Events

        self.m_button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_cancel)
        pub.subscribe(self.updateProgress, "update")
        pub.subscribe(self.on_finish, "finish")

    def updateProgress(self, step):
        self.progress += step
        self.gauge.SetValue(self.progress)

    def on_cancel(self, event):
        """Cancels the conversion process"""
        self.parent.work.stop()
        self.parent.work.join()
        pub.unsubscribe(self.updateProgress, "update")
        pub.unsubscribe(self.on_finish, "finish")
        self.Destroy()
        # pub.unsubscribe(self.if_abort, 'cancel')

    def on_finish(self):
        """conversion process finished"""
        pub.unsubscribe(self.updateProgress, "update")
        pub.unsubscribe(self.on_finish, "finish")
        self.Close()

    def __del__(self):
        pass


########################################################################################

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.btn = btn = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Start Thread")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onButton(self, event):
        btn = event.GetEventObject()
        btn.Disable()
        self.panel.work = WorkThread()
        self.dlg = ProgressDialog(self.panel)
        self.dlg.ShowModal()
        btn.Enable()

app = wx.App()
frame = MainFrame(None)
frame.Show(True)
# start the applications
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly! I tries to use sth similar with self.stop_work_thread as a flag to stop for-loop in WorkThread but it didn't work that time. Is it because I didn't use MainFrame as ProgressDialog's parent so it's not linked at all?

Comment: Possibly, but it didn't look like there was a way to stop the thread itself, just the progress bar. The `on_cancel` routine now stops the thread and waits for it to finish (the `.join` statement).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply!